# Read File From Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, outlook

I'm writing a script where I wish to write an HTML doc to a string from sharepoint.

```
Dim Content As String
Dim strShare As String: strShare = "\\link\to\share.html"
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile

Open strShare For Input As #iFile
    Content = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close #iFile
```

However, I find I get a "path/file access error" every time I run the script for the first time upon boot. Once I visit "\link\to\share.html" in IE for the first time, the path begins to resolve in the VBA script.

My only thought is that IE is performing some sort of "DNS Cache" that VBA can't do. Currently my workaround is to catch the error and force the URL to open in IE the first time the script is run. After that, every other HTML file under that share loads fine.

As a test, I tried switching between from what I understand is http:// formatting (forward slash) and WebDAV formatting (\\ formating), and only the backslash separated paths ever work. I also tried to resolve the share to an IP and try it that way, but that never worked.

My last thought is to try mapping the share to a drive letter name and then specifically accessing the share with G:\link\to\mapped\share.html. But I don't see this as an elegant solution, and wonder if it will receive the same error any way.

Is there something blatant that I do not understand about WebDAV, Windows file handling, and VBA file inputs? There's something weird going on under the hood with resolving that shared domain, and I can't seem to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps [here](https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/unc-path-naming-for-files-stored-on-sharepoint-2/) and an example below that I used.

2 things though: I only worked with Excel files on Sharepoint and I was already logged in there.

```
Dim oFSO As Object 
'Dim oFolder As Object 'if needed
'Dim oFile As Object 'if needed

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("\\sharepoint.site.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\")

'For Each oFolder In oFolder.SubFolders 'loops through folders
'    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files 'loops through files
'        'do stuff
'    Next oFile
'Next oFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you want to do.  Do you want to check out files from SP and check files back into SP?

```
Sub testing()
    Dim docCheckOut As String
    'docCheckOut = "//office.bt.com/sites/Training/Design Admin/Training Plan/adamsmacro.xlsm"
    docCheckOut = "http://your_path_here/ExcelList.xlsb"
    Call UseCheckOut(docCheckOut)
End Sub

Sub UseCheckOut(docCheckOut As String)
     ' Determine if workbook can be checked out.
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(docCheckOut) = True Then
        Workbooks.CheckOut docCheckOut
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check out this document at this time."
    End If
End Sub
```

Or...do you want to list files in a SP folder?

```
Sub ListFiles()
    Dim folder As Variant
    Dim f As File
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim RowCtr As Integer
    Dim FPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    RowCtr = 1

    FPath = "http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents"
    For Each f In FPath
    'Set folder = fs.GetFolder("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Ryan_Folder")
    'For Each f In folder.Files
       Cells(RowCtr, 1).Value = f.Name
       RowCtr = RowCtr + 1
    Next f
End Sub

Sub test()
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Ryan_Folder")
    'Set colSubfolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    'For Each objSubfolder In colSubfolders

       Cells(RowCtr, 1).Value = f.Name
       RowCtr = RowCtr + 1

    'Next
End Sub
```